# PHP Session expires even when actively used

Tags: php, session

My PHP sessions expire even if the user is actively using the website and the session is being updated. I even went as far as adding a count variable to the session that is updated on every visit to any page. No matter what I change, the session expires after 24 minutes. What settings should I be investigating?

Comment: is the same happening on your development machine or only on live site?

Comment: They are the same. It is a VPS with a single php.ini file for all domains and sub-domains.

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Comment: What code? `$_SESSION['count']++`